# Android: how to use the 9patch creator?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a stretchable scroll handle for my app.

The first  image is the scrollhandle.9.png that I include in my app's resources.

The second image shows what this 9patch image looks like when used in my app.

Any advice on how to accomplish a stretchable scroll handle?

[image]

[image]

Edit:  With help from posters, I was able to get an image that works.  I added it below to help those who may find this in the future.

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch So the black pixels indicate which parts get stretched (in your case). Right now you're stretching the top of the triangle and the top/bottom pixel row

Comment: Sorry for double comment but it would actually help to know how it's supposed to look like (make a sketch or whatever). This way I or someone else could show you how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area covered by the top and the left black line(dots) will be used while scaling your image. This area will be highlighted to you when you click the "show patch" option.  You can see how the image scales by using the "Patch scale" option given in the draw9patch tool.

The area covered by the right and bottom lines(dots) will hold the content for the background.
Eg: You can define boundaries for the text inside 9 patch image for editor background. For your case you don't need right and bottom lines.

So for your case place two dots  at the top corner and two dots at the left corner. Make sure patches doesn't fall in the arrow image of the scroll(if they do fall your arrow image will also get stretched) . Try putting the dots only in the left and top lines till you get the desired preview with "Patch scale" option.

Comment: This led me to the solution, though I did something a bit differently than you described.  I added my final nine patch image to the original post, to help others in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only one dot (instead of four) at the top and bottom left, and one at image top center, it should stretch the way you want it to.

Comment: Ok, I tried this and updated my post to show the images it produced.  I used 2 dots at top center because the image has an even number of pixels (across).